# Django sending email from_email arguments

Tags: python, django, email

Why is there `from_email` argument in `send_email` django function, when we specify `EMAIL_HOST_USER` in `settings.py` module?

Comment: [`EMAIL_HOST_USER`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#email-host-user) defines the Username to use for the SMTP server defined in `EMAIL_HOST`

Comment: You tagged this as the Unix program `sendmail`. Are you really using that?

Comment: @abdul-niyas-p-m but why we still need `from_email` argument?